# How to set a relative tomcat docbase?

Tags: tomcat, configuration, contextpath

This is my Context definition:

```
<Context docBase="../myupperProject/" path="/something" />
```

If I let this run in tomcat the problem is that tomcat adds a absolute path like

c:\something\something../myupperProject

How can I get rid of the first part? I just want to tell tomcat to use a upper folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with maven. 
The parameter is exchanged with the maven resource filtering.